# Copy data to temporary table from two different databases having same table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, temp-tables, union-all

I have two databases. One database has current year data and the other has previous year data.

I want to copy data into a temporary table from a table named `tbl_Records` which is available in both databases and data from a temporary table. I have used inner join for the same.

```
select a.* 
into #copy 
from #temp t 
inner join Records2021..tbl_Records r on t.uniqueno = r.uniqueno
where isdeleted = 0
```

The table `tbl_Records` has around 150 columns and all columns are required. Hence preferred `*`

Now I need to include the database `Records2020` for the previous year. How can I do so?

Using a CTE may help. But the issue is I need to specify all column names for the same which is tedious. Is there an **easier way** to do this as I need to implement this in almost 50-60 different stored procedures for different tables.

My ultimate goal is just to get data from both databases together into one temporary table.

Code attempt:

```
If object_id('tempdb..#copy') is not null
begin
    drop table #copy
end

If object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
begin
    drop table #temp
end;

with cte as
(
    select a.* 
    from #temp t 
    inner join Records2021..tbl_Records r on t.uniqueno = r.uniqueno
    where isdeleted = 0

    union all

    select a.* 
    from #temp t 
    inner join Records2020..tbl_Records r on t.uniqueno = r.uniqueno
    where isdeleted = 0
) 
select a.* 
into #copy 
from cte   /*this does not work as I need to mention all 150 columns here.*/
```

I'm open to any other alternatives too.

DBMS : Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: 150 columns is usually a design flaw, as is having separate tables for different years

Comment: @Charlieface Can u breif on how is it a design flaw.

Comment: @Charlieface Can u brief me on how is it a design flaw. To avoid slowness in the system data of every previous year is archived. Kindly explain how is it a flaw?

Comment: A well indexed table should not cause much performance issues due to its size. A million rows takes max 20 lookups in a B-tree, a billion rows only takes max 30 lookups, in other words `log2(n)`. Don't wreck your design because of "performance", there are much better solutions. You would also have far less *performace* issues if your table was properly normalized (it is possible to have a normalized table with many columns, but unlikely).

Comment: See also https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/ and https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/02/10/sql-server-top-reasons-for-slow-performance/ and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/08/do-you-have-tables-in-your-tables/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using `UNION ALL` but pay attention that `#temp` and `tbl_Records` table must have the same structure (columns and data type).

```
SELECT 
    *
INTO 
    #copy
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM #temp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * 
    FROM [Records2021]..[tbl_Records]
) AS tbl
WHERE 
    tbl.isdeleted = 0
```

If table structure is different, use `SELECT ... INTO` for one table, and for the second table adjust `INSERT INTO` with needed columns.